# Removing spaces from string

Tags: android, string, replace, trim

I'm trying to remove all the spaces from a string derived from user input, but for some reason it isn't working for me. Here is my code.

```
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonGo:
            String input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
            input = String.replace(" ", "");
            url = ur + input + l;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, Main.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("URL", url);
            start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 289, accepted):

```
String  input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
input = input.replace(" ", "");
```

Sometimes you would want to remove only the spaces at the beginning or end of the String (not the ones in the middle). If that's the case you can use `trim`:

```
input = input.trim();
```

Comment: You'll use *replace("l","")* and *replace("h","")*

Comment: `.toString()` isn't necessary (anymore?) on `getText()`

Comment: I am try using trim() .I have the same error

Comment: Using kotlin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932163/removing-spaces-from-string/74973496#74973496

Answer (score 29):

When I am reading numbers from contact book, then it doesn't worked
I used

```
number=number.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

It worked and for url you may use

```
url=url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 10):

I also had this problem. To sort out the problem of spaces in the middle of the string this line of code always works:

```
String field = field.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String urle = HOST + url + value;
```

Then return the values from:

```
urle.replace(" ", "%20").trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

String res ="   Application   "
res=res.trim();

o/p: Application

Note: White space ,blank space are trim or removed

Comment: it's helpful for string space trimed.

Answer (score 0):

**Using kotlin you can write like:**

```
val resultStr = yourString.replace(" ", "")
```

**Example:**

```
val yourString = "Android Kotlin"
val resultStr = yourString.replace(" ", "")
```

**Result:** AndroidKotlin