# Work with the link with special character (e.g. traditional chinese , empty space) in android

Tags: android, localization, encode, url-encoding

I am working with special character in URL for android

However, I encounter two problem

1) empty space

If I have a query inside url

```
e.g. test.php?test=aaa bbbb cccc
```

Then the query will not include bbbb and cccc,  I learnt that I should replace the " " to %20, however, instead of using `replace(" ","%20")`, how can I do it in more standard way?

2) traditional chinese in url

I have an image url like this:

```
http://oshc.zizsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/1-職安健資訊產品目錄2013-220x300.png
```

If I directly pass to android, it fail. but if I copy the link to my desktop browser , it change to like this, then I paste it on android, it works

```
"http://oshc.zizsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/1-%E8%81%B7%E5%AE%89%E5%81%A5%E8%B3%87%E8%A8%8A%E7%94%A2%E5%93%81%E7%9B%AE%E9%8C%842013-220x300.png";
```

What should I do to encode to this?

Thanks for helping

Update:

it change to

```
http%3A%2F%2Foshc.zizsoft.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F12%2FSQ1-351x300.jpg
```

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try trimming the url, it wil remove the spaces from url. I guess its bit more staanddard way to solve this issue.

2) This problem is eactly due to the encoding issues. Our Android default encoding is cp1252...and those strings will not be encoded in the same way so when it used in the code its automatically changes to some other symbols. So try changing the encoding of the project and string to the same like UTF-8 or something. You can change project encoding by
Properties> Resources> Encoding

Hope my suggesions will help you a bit.

Try this links also
1. [Trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932163/removing-spaces-from-string)
2. [Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically encode and decode URLs then use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class available in Java as well as Android.

```
// To encode URL 
URLEncoder.encode(url, charset);
// to decode url
URLDecoder.decode(url, charset);
```